# Is it a well-known sequence of polynomials?

Tags: integration, polynomials, fourier-series, bernoulli-polynomials

Let consider $(P_n)_{n\ge 0}$ a sequence of polynomials given by :

$\forall t \in \mathbb{R}$; $\ P_0(t)=1$.

$\forall n\ge 1$; $\ (P_n)'=P_{n-1}$.

$\forall n\ge 1$; $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1} P_n(t) \mathrm{d}t=0$.

It seems similar to Bernoulli's polynomials.

Moreover for $n=1$, do we have $P_1(1)=P_1(0)$ ? If we use the fact that : $\displaystyle P_1(1)-P_1(0)=\ \int_{0}^{1} P_1'(t) \mathrm{d}t=\int_{0}^{1} P_0(t) \mathrm{d}t=\int_{0}^{1} \mathrm{d}t=1.$ Then $P_1(1)\neq P_1(0)$.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Yes, Bernouilli's polynomials, to a constant factor.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Bernoulli polynomials don't satisfy the second condition since $(B_n)'=nB_{n-1}$. I'm not convinced such a sequence exists.

Comment: @CyclotomicField Indeed it's the main difference with Bernoulli's polynomials... This polynomials sequence can be useful to evaluate series (in the theory of Fourier series) !

Comment: @Maman How do you know such a sequence exists?

Comment: @CyclotomicField: I said to a constant factor. (In fact $n!$.)

Comment: @YvesDaoust But it's not the same at all so I don't see how it's relevant.

Comment: @CyclotomicField: "not the same at all": please elaborate.

Comment: @YvesDaoust what do you mean by "$n!$" ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust $nP_k \neq P_k$. I don't know how else to make that more plain.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yes but I mean why the factor would be "n!" ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust The bernouilli polynomials exist. I'm not convinced any polynomials satisfy this criteria let alone a whole sequence of them.

Comment: Review the definition of the Bernouilli polynomials !

Comment: @YvesDaoust I did and I pointed out the error you're making already. $n \neq 1$ for all $n$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I see now the mistake was mine. $B_n/n!$ works perfectly. Sorry for that.

Comment: @CyclotomicField: no problem, errare...